# Have Program Loop Continuously

Tags: java, loops

I'm writing a program for an instructor to input grades, average those grades, then give the total of all of the averages for that particular student. I've programmed it almost to it's entirety. The only issue I'm having is figuring out how to have the entire program loop continuously until the user presses 'enter' to quit. I've included my code below (and have updated it with my new code below it):

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class StudentGrades {
  public static void main(String[] args){

    //Declare Scanner and instantiate keyboard
    Scanner keyboard;
    keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

    //String to hold student name
    String StudentName;

    //Variables to hold number of grades entered
    int countOfGrades=0;
    int countOfGrades2=0;

    //Variables to hold individual grade inputted
    float inputtedGrade=0;
    float inputtedTestGrade=0;
    float inputtedExamGrade=0;

    //Variables to hold the total sum of grades entered
    float totalSumOfGrades=0;
    float totalSumOfGrades2=0;

    //Prompt user for input
    System.out.print("Input student name: ");
    StudentName = keyboard.nextLine();

    //Prompt the user for grade
    System.out.print("Input student's homework/quiz grade: ");

    //Get grade from user
    inputtedGrade = keyboard.nextFloat();

    //Loop while grade is greater than zero
    while(inputtedGrade > 0){

        //Add grade to sum total
        totalSumOfGrades=totalSumOfGrades+inputtedGrade;

        //Increment counter of grades
        countOfGrades++;

        //Prompt user for grade
        System.out.print("Input student's homework/quiz grade: ");

        //Get grade from user
        inputtedGrade=keyboard.nextFloat();

    }//Ending bracket of while loop

    //Calculate and output average of grades
    System.out.print("Average homework/quiz grade is: ");
    System.out.println((totalSumOfGrades/countOfGrades));

    //Prompt user for test score
    System.out.print("Input student's test grade: ");
    inputtedTestGrade = keyboard.nextFloat();

    //Loop while grade is greater than zero
    while(inputtedTestGrade > 0) {

        //Add grade to sum total
        totalSumOfGrades2=totalSumOfGrades2+inputtedTestGrade;

        //Increment counter of grades
        countOfGrades2++;

        //Prompt user for grade
        System.out.print("Input student's test grade: ");

        //Get grade from user
        inputtedTestGrade=keyboard.nextFloat();     
    }//Ending bracket of while loop

    //Calculate and output average of grades
    System.out.print("Average test grade is: ");
    System.out.println((totalSumOfGrades2/countOfGrades2));

    //Prompt user for exam score
    System.out.print("Enter student's exam grade: ");
    inputtedExamGrade=keyboard.nextFloat();

    //Double to hold average values then convert to int
    double avgHomework = (totalSumOfGrades/countOfGrades)*.2;
    double avgTest = (totalSumOfGrades2/countOfGrades2)*.5;
    double avgExam = (inputtedExamGrade)*.3;
    float avgHW = (float) avgHomework;
    float avgT = (float) avgTest;
    float avgEx = (float) avgExam;

    //Output student grade
    System.out.println("The grade for this student is: " +(avgHW+avgT+avgEx));

    //Close keyboard
    keyboard.close();

  }//Ending bracket of method main

}//Ending bracket of class StudentGrades


import java.util.Scanner;

public class StudentGrades {
    public static void main(String[] args){
    while (true){ 

    //Declare Scanner and instantiate keyboard
    Scanner keyboard;
    keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

    //Strings to hold values
    String StudentName;
    String cont;

    //Variables to hold number of grades entered
    int countOfGrades=0;
    int countOfGrades2=0;

    //Variables to hold individual grade inputted
    float inputtedGrade=0;
    float inputtedTestGrade=0;
    float inputtedExamGrade=0;

    //Variables to hold the total sum of grades entered
    float totalSumOfGrades=0;
    float totalSumOfGrades2=0;

    //Prompt user for input
    System.out.print("Input student name: ");
    StudentName = keyboard.nextLine();

    //Prompt the user for grade
    System.out.print("Input student's homework/quiz grade: ");

    //Get grade from user
    inputtedGrade = keyboard.nextFloat();

    //Loop while grade is greater than zero
        while(inputtedGrade > 0){

        //Add grade to sum total
        totalSumOfGrades=totalSumOfGrades+inputtedGrade;

        //Increment counter of grades
        countOfGrades++;

        //Prompt user for grade
        System.out.print("Input student's homework/quiz grade: ");

        //Get grade from user
        inputtedGrade=keyboard.nextFloat();

    }//Ending bracket of while loop

    //Calculate and output average of grades
    System.out.print("Average homework/quiz grade is: ");
    System.out.println((totalSumOfGrades/countOfGrades));

    //Prompt user for test score
    System.out.print("Input student's test grade: ");
    inputtedTestGrade = keyboard.nextFloat();

    //Loop while grade is greater than zero
    while(inputtedTestGrade > 0) {

            //Add grade to sum total
            totalSumOfGrades2=totalSumOfGrades2+inputtedTestGrade;

            //Increment counter of grades
            countOfGrades2++;

            //Prompt user for grade
            System.out.print("Input student's test grade: ");

            //Get grade from user
            inputtedTestGrade=keyboard.nextFloat();     
    }//Ending bracket of while loop

    //Calculate and output average of grades
    System.out.print("Average test grade is: ");
    System.out.println((totalSumOfGrades2/countOfGrades2));

    //Prompt user for exam score
    System.out.print("Enter student's exam grade: ");
    inputtedExamGrade=keyboard.nextFloat();

    //Double to hold average values then convert to int
    double avgHomework = (totalSumOfGrades/countOfGrades)*.2;
    double avgTest = (totalSumOfGrades2/countOfGrades2)*.5;
    double avgExam = (inputtedExamGrade)*.3;
    float avgHW = (float) avgHomework;
    float avgT = (float) avgTest;
    float avgEx = (float) avgExam;

    //Output student grade
    System.out.println("The grade for this student is: " +(avgHW+avgT+avgEx));

    //Prompt user for continuity input
    System.out.println("Would you like to input another student's grades? (y/n)");
      cont = keyboard.next();
      if (cont.equalsIgnoreCase("n")) {
          break;
      }
    //Close keyboard
    keyboard.close();

    }//Ending bracket of very first while loop

}//Ending bracket of method main

}//Ending bracket of class StudentGrades
```

Comment: The user presses "enter" many times in your program. Which one would end the program?

Comment: @4castle This is what I was wondering too. For my solution, I instead prompted the user at the end of the code.

Comment: I'm in my very first programming class and we've been taught to press enter after each user input.

Comment: @SMcGwier That is completely fine. We are just wondering when you want to exit the program (from which input). My solution should work fine for your code.

Comment: There is no specific end to it. It just needs to end when the 'instructor' is finished inputting all of the grades for each student. So, in your code, I put the while(true) at the very top (immediately under the first two lines of code) and the rest of it immediately before I close the keyboard input?

Answer (score 2):

You can do this:

```
while(true){

  //put code in here

  System.out.println("Continue?(y/n)");
  String cont = keyboard.nextLine();
  if(cont.equalsIgnoreCase("n")){
    break;
  }
}
```

Comment: This is essentially what the algorithm will look like, though you might just do `while(true)` and then put `break;` in the `if` statement.

Comment: @4castle Edited my answer.

Comment: Ok, so, I used this in my code but received an error message saying "No Such Element Exception". I can't figure out where this error is coming from, as my program was running perfectly before I used this code.

Comment: I'm not sure how to find that information. This is what the error message looks like: Input student name: Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException: No line found
 at java.util.Scanner.nextLine(Scanner.java:1540)
 at StudentGrades.main(StudentGrades.java:33)

Comment: So line 33 is causing the error. Please send line 33 (or whichever line it may be now)

Comment: Line 33 is: StudentName = keyboard.nextLine();

The error only happens when I input 'y' in response to running the program again. If I input 'n' it doesn't create the error.

Comment: Did you call "keyboard.close();" before that line?

Comment: @SMcGwier Try changing "String cont = keyboard.nextLine();" to "String cont = keyboard.next();"

Comment: No. I thought at first I needed to take out the 'Line' portion but then it doesn't allow me to input last names (obviously just having 'next' allows for one word). I don't think it's an error of the two input lines with that string not matching.

Comment: Well, changing that line fixed it for me. It seems to be working on my computer?

Comment: Please edit your original post with your current code (but keep your old code above it)

Comment: @SMcGwier I got your code working by deleting "keyboard.close();"

Comment: That worked for me, too. Wonder why it won't allow the Scanner to close...? So strange. Thanks so much for your help! You're awesome!

Comment: @SMcGwier It's because you can't close the Scanner if you plan to reuse it (I think). No problem though! You can choose my answer as best answer if it answered your question fully.